# How to display an update to a UITableView before a the view closes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView displaying a set of options from which the user will select.  When a row is selected the table will update to add a checkmark to that row (and remove it from all others).  All is good so far.

What I want to do is close the view after the user makes the row selection but I want the tableview to update first so that the user can see the checkmark move to the correct row (however briefly this may display for).

If I do the following:

```
[myTableView reloadData];
[parentView closeDialog];
```

the table update will not show, the dialog will simply close.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this technique to call closeDialog after a delay

```
//afterDelay parameter represents number of seconds to delay the method call
[parentView performSelector:@selector(closeDialog) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0 ];
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Add `self` prefix and add some delay using `performselector`

```
[self.myTableView reloadData];
[parentView closeDialog];
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: This doesn't answer his question

Comment: @obuseme: It's and but i forgot to mention delay..your and can not update table..